# Next.js: how to async load image before user navigates to the component where it is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, preload, next-images

I'm working on a Next.js application which consists of a single page, however, users are able to click on a few buttons that should reveal an image. I want to force clients to download the image before the user reveals this image through a click. Note that the images are resolved dynamically at build time, so I cannot preload them inside `<head>`. My `getStaticProps` retrieves the image URLs, and then inside `useEffect` of my page, I commit these URLs to a Redux store.

I thought that I may be able to start loading the images inside `useEffect` and commit the resulting `Image` from `next/image` into the Redux store from where they can be retrieved by my component that displays this image. However, committing ReactElement values into Redux appears to be an anti-pattern, so I'm not sure about this approach.

is there a way to canonical way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it turned out to be easier than I thought. All I needed to do was loop over my images inside `useEffect` and load them like this:

```
const image = new Image()
image.src = imageUrl
```

That is all, I don't need to pass them down anywhere, because they get cached, so when I call the same URL from my component later, it gets loaded immediately.